# Visualization of continous availability of several URLs

Tags: javascript, url, monitoring, visualization, availability

I need to monitor several Sites (say around 300 Urls) for its availability continuously. I can understand that Checking for all the sites availability and populating it on a single dashboard with individual sites may not be a good Visualization solution.

Can someone help me with what kind of visualization this use case can be achieved. I am using nodejs app for getting the data of the sites availability at regular intervals.

Looking for suggestion with any opensource framework is also great.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I think here there are two different challenges: design and technical implementation. Which of the two have you tried to attack first?

Comment: I explored using Uptime, Parallec as well. My challenge using Parallec is that it can check the Host only. When i try a complete URL it fails. 
However, Visualization challenge is my primary concern. One thought I have is to have a chart (say pie chart) created to display the distribution of different status codes/messages on reaching those URLs. In addition to that display the pages which are non 200 OK status ones. But challenge becomes very high when the number of URLs are more. So primarily i am wondering what kind of visualization would suit in this case.

Comment: Getting the status continuously of several URLs is not a problem. But I am wondering about the Visualization/Reporting of such data. Consider I have data of all those URL's availability status at a particular timeinterval is I have already and it is run periodically to collect the stats.

Comment: What kind of question you want to answer? I.e. All the urls are up? Few are up and some down? Some rule are down? The tricky part of visualisations is find the question you want to ask.

Comment: Thanks MarcoL...Your last question in the comment, answered my own question.

So, I will create my own visualization with a pie chart with different status codes. On clicking the appropriate ones I will try to list all the host urls which are in that state. Mainly i m trying to identify the non-OK status based urls. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom visualization with a pie chart with different status codes. On clicking the appropriate ones I will try to list all the host urls which are in that state. Mainly i m trying to identify the non-OK status based urls